# How to prevent users from updating the app in play store?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I just released an update for my upp, however, it crashes the app immedietly, how do I prevent current users from updating while my (hopefully) fix-update is pending?

Comment: This is not flutter specific, the tag doesnt fit

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these two packages to notify your users that there is a new version:

- [Upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader)
- [In app update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update)

I hope this will help you